# Study the convergence or divergence of the improper integral $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt x\cdot \ln x} dx.$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am stuck in solving the following exercise, please help me with the improper integral

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt x\cdot \ln x} dx.$$
I am asked to determine whether it is divergent or convergent.

Comment: Hint: $\ln x<\sqrt x$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: this means it diverges by D.C.T am i correct?

Comment: Depends on what D.C.T. is

Comment: by comparison test this integral is gretear than 1/x and 1/x diverges by p-integral so this is my way is it correct?

Comment: Almost. There is an $N$ so that ${1\over x\ln x}>{1\over x}$ for $x\ge N$. Since $\int_N^\infty 1/x\,dx$ diverges, so does your integral. I think you can take $N=2$, actually; so your argument is ok (up to being badly phrased).

Answer (score 1):

Setting $t=\sqrt{x}$, we have
$$
\int_2^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\ln x}\,dx=\int_{\sqrt{2}}^\infty\frac{2t}{t\ln t^2}\,dt=\int_{\sqrt{2}}^\infty\frac{1}{\ln t}\,dt
\ge\int_{\sqrt{2}}^\infty\frac{1}{t}\,dt=\infty.
$$